# Deploy with ansible: No such file or directory - "/usr/local/bin/ssh-bash"

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I`m deploying to all-inkl.com with ansible 2.4.0.0. I get a strange error:

```
System info:
  Ansible 2.4.0.0; Linux
  Trellis 1.0.3: April 30th, 2019
---------------------------------------------------
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
The full traceback is:
  File "/tmp/ansible_bpaYEe/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2744, in run_command
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

fatal: [staging_hostname]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "/usr/local/bin/ssh-bash -c 'ps -p 1 -o comm|tail -n 1'", 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "fact_path": "/etc/ansible/facts.d", 
            "filter": "*", 
            "gather_subset": [
                "all"
            ], 
            "gather_timeout": 10
        }
    }, 
    "rc": 2
}
```

The same deploy works to other servers without a problem.

I do not know how to debug, because I do not find infos about what "/usr/local/bin/ssh-bash" command could come from. My other server do not execute this.

Im using the trellis playbook: https://github.com/roots/trellis
There is no command "ssh-bash" in it, that is why I am suprised. I don`t know, from which ansible command this is triggered.

Does somebody have ideas on how to find out whats wrong?

Comment: Can you show your playbook ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run something called `/usr/local/bin/ssh-bash` that doesn't exist on this particular server. Have you checked to make sure it's there?

Comment: @Zeitounator: I updated my post. I`m using the trellis playbook

Comment: @larsks: Exactly. The Problem is: I have no idea, why my playbook has the idea to call this command, because it is not included in the playbook. It does not try to call it on other servers.